# Can I return an object of ofstream to initinialize another object of ofstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, iostream

I would like to open a file in one function return the open file object to main, and use it another 
function to populate the file. It appears the compiler is telling me that I"m trying to access a private member of iostream. Is there a way to do this and how?

```
ofstream& open_outfile()
{
    string outfile;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> outfile;

    ofstream ost(outfile.c_str());
    if (!ost) error("can't open out file");

    return ost;
}


//...............

int main()
{

//...some code

    ofstream ost = open_outfile();//attempt 1

    //ofstream ost() = open_outfile();//attempt 2

    populate_outfile(ost, readings);

    keep_window_open();

}
```

This syntax which I found in "The c++ programming language" seems to work:

```
ofstream ost = move(open_outfile());
```

Which is better? Declaring the object in main and passing by reference ost to both function? Or using the move constructor?

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary. And `ofstream ost = x()` is attempting to copy-construct `ost` (where `x()` is an lvalue).

Answer (score 3):

The various stream classes have move constructors in C++11, i.e., you can move a `std::ofstream` from a function and initialize a `std::ofstream` from it (trying to initialize a `std::ostream` from an `std::ofstream` does **not** work). That is, assuming you compile with `-std=c++11` and the versions of `libstdc++` shipping with your version of `gcc` is updated to support these constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a reference to an `ofstream` object into the function:

```
void open_outfile(/*out*/ ofstream &ost)
{
    string filename;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> filename;

    ost.open(filename.c_str());
    if (!ost) error("can't open out file");
}
```

Then, in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream ost;
    open_outfile(ost);
    populate_outfile(ost, readings);
    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: not necessary now that we have move semantics, but this is a good answer if the OP doesn't have a newer compiler